# Keeping rake jobs:work running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using delayed_job to run jobs, with new jobs being added every minute by a cronjob.

Currently I have an issue where the rake jobs:work task, currently started with 'nohup rake jobs:work &' manually, is randomly exiting.

While God seems to be a solution to some people, the extra memory overhead is rather annoying and I'd prefer a simpler solution that can be restarted by the deployment script (Capistrano).

Is there some bash/Ruby magic to make this happen, or am I destined to run a monitoring service on my server with some horrid hacks to allow the unprivelaged account the site deploys to the ability to restart it?

Comment: `daemons` gem provides the ability to daemonize, monitor and restart the process. Check out an example at https://github.com/prakashmurthy/daemons_example I am guessing it will be similar to `God` in terms of memory overhead since it starts a separate monitoring process. I am not aware of any way to accomplish the same via deployment script.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use `foreman`. It allows you to start any number of jobs in development by using `foreman run`, and then export your configuration (number of processes per type, limits etc) as upstart scripts, to make them available to Ubuntu's upstart (why invoking God when the operating system already has this for free??).

The configuration file, `Procfile`, is also exactly the same file Heroku uses for process configuration, so with just one file you get three process management systems covered.